# Fail Upload file in Selenium webdriver using Robot class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am pressing at open button , that brings the windows dialog , and i want to select from it  an image to upload .
`(driver.findElement(By.id("myID")).sendKeys("C:\\myPhoto.jpg");`  NOT WORKING )

i tried using robot class , but it does nothing .

```
     //Image upload code
      driver.findElement(By.id("image_file"));
      driver.findElement(By.id("image_file")).click();  \\ window dialog opens
      uploadImage("C:\\myPhoto.jpg");
      Thread.sleep(500);

  public static void setClipBoardData(String string){
      //Copying the path of the file to the clipboard 
      //StringSelection class used for copy and paste operations.
      StringSelection stringselect = new StringSelection(string);//Putting the path of the image to upload
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringselect, null);
  }

  public static void uploadImage(String imagelocation){
      try{
          //Setting clipboard with image location
          setClipBoardData(imagelocation);
        //Some sleep time to detect the window popup
          Thread.sleep(500);
          //native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
          Robot robot =  new Robot();
          robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
          robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
          robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
          robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        //To Click on the "Open" button to upload files
          robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
          robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
          robot.delay(500);
      } catch (Exception exp) {
          exp.printStackTrace();
      }
```

HTML  -
here

```
     HTML  -<div id="thumbnail" class="toolTipTranslate left-Arrow coverImageDimension" top="-=535px" left="580px" rtl-left="-702px" translatekey="ACTIVITY_DETAILS_IMAGE_TIP" width="264px">
<input id="activityIconFocusField" type="text" onclick="$('#thumbnailUploadImage').trigger('click');" readonly="" name="activityIcon">here
```

Comment: you can try javascript? like `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('activityIconFocusField').text='path';");

Comment: I tried your uploadimage function after opening google page, it works fine. so It seems that issue is with the focus of textbox, which you can try to get by pressing tab or some shortcut key(like alt+n or alt+f if available).